# Is there a way for emacs to not be in typing mode, similar to vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

I'd like to press something like C-j to enter a mode where hitting any alphabet key will no longer type the key, but instead do something else I've mapped it to do, until I exit the mode by pressing C-j again.

For example, in this mode, I'd like to make hitting i j k l make me go up left right down. Currently I hit C-i, C-j, C-k, C-l everytime I try to go up, left, right, down, and I'd like to stop having to hold down the control key.

I believe this is something vim has, and was wondering if emacs has it too.

Comment: You've already discovered `god-mode`. You may also be interested in a vi-emulation layer like `evil`.

Comment: `evil-mode` is included by default since emacs 23. Try it out now with `M-x evil-mode`, and see the documentation at http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil I had the same requirements as you and I didn't quit evil since then !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's this: https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode

more chars